# Reading in columns for a .csv file

Tags: python

I need to read in data from a .csv file that is outputted by an iOS application.

[image]

In doing so, I need to print independent columns and their data when they are called (if someone inputs 'interval', the whole interval column must be printed).

I've opened and read it my file, but I don't know how to store it and then recall it when I need it. I honestly do not know how to even try it, I'm used to be able to use `line.split(separator)`, but the data is already stored in a table.

```
# EPIC Sports variable stores, translating boditrak to tangible values.

def main ():
    print ("Welcome to Epic Sports Boditrak Info processor")
    filename = input("Enter the full name of the file you'd like to read: ")
    f = open(filename,"r")
    lines = []
    lines = f.readlines ()
    for x in lines:
        print (x)
    f.close ()
    interval = [ ] 
    total_force = [ ]
    left_force = [ ]
    right_force = [ ]
    COPx_disp = [ ]
    COPy_disp = [ ]
    COPx_velo = [ ]
    COPy_velo = [ ]

main ()
```

I get `IndexError` when I try to store as a list, then recall list. I believe there are too many trials for it to be a list.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what a sample input file looks like so we can see the actual format of the data being read. It would also be useful to see the code you wrote that gave you the `IndexError`. Python has a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module that makes reading them very easy.

Comment: Don't edit the answer! [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a file is easy and fast for amounts of text that can be displayed.  Do you need to store some data structure?  I recommend you parse the headings, and then at each request iterate across all lines.

I can't commend on your line.split(separator) issue without seeing the data.  If it is XML issues then I can only suggest an XML parser.  Otherwise, perhaps you need to do some trickery and define your own split function for this type of file.

Regarding the index errors, perhaps you have incomplete rows?   Catch exceptions as you iterate through the file in that case.   Since you no longer are trying to store the file as some list structure, you should have less issue handling these.

Comment: I've attached a sample of the data, there are 250 subsequent trials like that.